# What would happen if somebody ate a wild-shaped Druid, and then the Druid changed back inside them?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

Let's say that a medium-sized Druid wild shapes into something like a fly (fine sized) and flies into a medium-sized NPC's mouth while they were talking, gets swallowed, and then wild-shapes back into their humanoid form. What would happen in this instance? Would the Druid take damage? Would the NPC take damage?

Comment: ♫ ...perhaps he'll die?

Comment: [Related](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67501/what-happens-when-wild-shape-polymorph-runs-out-in-a-space-thats-too-small/67517#67517), but not quite a dupe as there's no hostile NPC in play there...

Comment: As an aside, an excellent way to interrogate an NPC is to let them know they just swallowed your Druid on accident and if they don't talk he'll change back.

Comment: @Dumpcats You should probably address two different cases: (1) the Druid Wild Shaped into something smaller than he is normally, and (2) the Druid Wild Shaped into something larger than he is normally.  Given the issue of "swallowed" Druid, that will potentially make a difference.  This comment was brought to you by _Friends of Boa Constrictors; Large and Small_

Comment: Do sizes smaller than Tiny even really exist in 5e?

Comment: If none of the answers are satisfying can you please clarify what your question is.

Comment: I think this happened on Tru Blood.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Monster Manual and DMG have 2 possible solutions to this:

- you could treat it like the same mechanics that the Tarrasque (MM p.286-7) uses to swallow, but scaled down to whoever swallowed the druid, or
- use the "inside an object" (as in the *Daern's Instant Fortress*) mechanic from the DMG, where both would take force damage based on their size: most likely 1d10 if they were both medium humanoids.

Comment: I think your second scenario is probably as close as I'm going to get

Comment: The second case sounds good. Still, though, I don't quite understand how it resolves, since we still have the problem that there's not enough space inside the one who shallowed the Druid. How would you resolve that? 1d10 damage and then, what? Where's the Druid?

Comment: @AlbertMasclans the 1d10 rule generally goes like: "if the creature/PC ends its turn inside an object then move it to the nearest empty square where it lands prone. it takes 1d10 damage for every 5 feet of movement"

Answer (score 2):

As a DM, I would rule that it would kill both of them. The NPC would hemorrhage to death; the druid would be suffocated. There's no provision in the rules for stopping such a transformation in mid-change; it all happens in seconds. And the druid would automatically revert to human form upon falling unconscious, which would happen quickly to a fly immersed in stomach acid.

*Elemental* Wild Shape would be another story -- a fire elemental would burn its way out, an air elemental could simply be exhaled, an earth elemental would shatter the ribcage and pelvis, and a water elemental would turn the unhappy target into a high-pressure fountain -- but I don't see anything in the rules that allows transformation from beast shape to beast shape, from beast shape to elemental shape or from elemental shape to beast shape. So the druid couldn't turn into a fly, be swallowed, then turn directly into an elemental.

Here's the genuinely nasty trick: Thousand Forms, which allows the casting of *alter self* at will. Turn into a fly, zip down the esophagus, then use the Natural Weapons option and sprout sea urchin spines. *shudder*

Comment: There is a question of sequencing here -- either the NPC dies first from having a Druid erupting out of them chest-burster style, or the Druid dies before they can break free of their self-inflicted imprisonment.  Also, cross-shaping, while not covered by the rules explicitly, would generally be allowed (as the ability to shape is not suppressed in any way by shaping).

Answer (score -6):

I would assume he'd just stop growing until he came back out. In Pathfinder, when you're growing after being affected by an "enlarge person" spell, if you reach the limits of your confines, you stop growing.

Comment: I looked through the player's guide and couldn't find any explanation of this sort of scenario for *any* of the temporary transformation spells--polymorph, et al. I think this question may not be answerable unless/until some official clarification comes out. Aside, obviously, from personal opinion. Personally, I'd have the character either get barfed back up or comically explode the swallower depending on the particulars.

Comment: Hi Atlas--as @DaleM points out, your answer doesn't have any obvious bearing on the question asked. However, it might be useful if it were part of a "there's no rules for it in 5e, the most recent time D&D *et al.* had rules for this sort of thing was in PF, and here's what they had to say..." answer. If that's what you were going for, go ahead and edit the beginning of your post to be a little clearer about addressing 5e's lack of guidance.

Comment: Pathfinder is not D&D et al. It's a separate system and its rules have no relevance to the rules of D&D.