# What is "squeezing"?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement

This is probably really obvious, but I scoured the rulebooks and the SRD and I can't figure out what squeezing is.

For example:

> **Amorphous**. The pudding can move through a space as narrow as 1 inch wide without *squeezing*.

So what would a character *without* Amorphous have to do?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Check out the Player's Handbook, page 192:

> **Squeezing into a Smaller Space:**
>   A creature can squeeze through a space that is large enough for a creature one size smaller than it. Thus, a Large creature can squeeze through a passage that's only 5 feet wide. While squeezing through a space,
>   a creature must spend 1 extra foot for every foot it moves there, and it has disadvantage on attack rolls and Dexterity saving throws. Attack rolls against the creature have advantage while it’s in the smaller space.

Creatures without Amorphous are usually governed by that rule.

As pointed out by @Adeptus, the rule is also available in the [SRD](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/systems-reference-document-srd) (page 92) and the [Players Basic Rules](http://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop/players-basic-rules) (page 71 in the print version, *Combat > Movement and Position* in the web version).

Comment: So basically, when squeezing a creature moves at half speed?

Comment: Yes, and is also hindered when attacking, and easier to attack.

Comment: One aspect of this that I think is troublesome is that the space for medium and small creatures (5') is the same. Kobolds are small and would typically dig tunnels that are kobold sized. Medium creatures should be at a disadvantage while having to stoop and squeeze in these narrow tunnels.

Comment: @jbruni Rather than making them Kobold-sized, they should make them bacterium-sized.  Kobold can squeeze through any space a Tiny (i.e. *the absolute smallest*) creature can fit through, but humans can't squeeze through a 1-inch-diameter gap.

Comment: @jbruni Only the WIDTH for Medium and Small creatures is the same. If tunnels are defined as sized for Small creatures, then Medium creatures will have to squeeze. As you said, the height will be an issue.